# Convert MLtable object into a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a data asset in Azure Machine Learning.
I want to convert it into a Pyspark dataframe.
In the consume tab of the data asset, I get the code to convert it into a Pandas dataframe.
However this data is huge (1 Tb+) so it will not fit into a Pandas dataframe.

This is the code I am using:

```
import mltable
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

ml_client = MLClient.from_config(credential=DefaultAzureCredential())
data_asset = ml_client.data.get("data_asset_name", version="1")

tbl = mltable.load(data_asset.path)

df = tbl.to_pandas_dataframe()
df
```

The function

> to_pandas_dataframe()

Converts the MLTable into a pandas dataframe.

Is there any function/way that I would be able to convert it into a pyspark dataframe?

Comment: You can't create the spark dataframe but you can send the mltable as input to spark jobs in azureml.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If we cannot create a dataframe, how can we do spark operations on the mltable in the spark jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `mltable` data asset directly to Spark jobs; there is no need to create a Spark DataFrame. Here is the sample code:

```py
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient, spark, Input, Output
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

ml_client = MLClient(
    DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace
)

spark_job = spark(
    display_name="Titanic-Spark-Job-SDK-6",
    code="./src",
    entry={"file": "titanic.py"},
    driver_cores=1,
    driver_memory="2g",
    executor_cores=2,
    executor_memory="2g",
    executor_instances=2,
    resources={
        "instance_type": "Standard_E4s_v3",
        "runtime_version": "3.2.0",
    },
    inputs={
        "titanic_data": Input(
            type="mltable",
            path=data_asset.id,
            mode="direct"
        ),
    },
    outputs={
        "wrangled_data": Output(
            type="uri_folder",
            path="azureml://datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/data/wrangled/",
            mode="direct",
        ),
    },
    args="--titanic_data ${{inputs.titanic_data}} --wrangled_data ${{outputs.wrangled_data}}",
)

returned_spark_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(spark_job)

# Wait until the job completes
ml_client.jobs.stream(returned_spark_job.name)
```

Here, I have given the input type as `mltable` and path data asset id.

The output is written to the wrangled folder.

[image]

If you still want to create pandas dataframe only way is using pandas dataframe in serverless spark compute.

```py
spark.createDataFrame(pandas_dataframe)
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/quickstart-spark-jobs.md) github for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I would need to do exploratory data analysis on this dataset and so I would need to do it in a  notebook